# Unable to enter the value to input textbox

Tags: selenium, capybara

I need help solving how to enter the value to input text box associated with the table cell wrapped inside tables `td`

the html is:

```
<td role="gridcell">
  <span style="width: 95px;" class="k-widget k-numerictextbox campaignBid">
    <span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default">
      <input type="text" class="k-formatted-value campaignBid k-input valid" tabindex="0" style="display: inline;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
      <input type="text" style="display: none;" value="0.0079" class="campaignBid k-input valid" id="mb_2" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0.0079" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="0.0079" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false">
      <span class="k-select"><span class="k-link" unselectable="on"><span title="Increase value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" unselectable="on">Increase value</span></span><span class="k-link" unselectable="on"><span title="Decrease value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">Decrease value</span>
      </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
</td>
```

I have tried using builder perform: 
    `bvar = first(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input")`
    `builder=page.driver.browser.action`
    `builder.key_down(:control).click(bvar.native).send_keys('a').send_keys("#{value}").perform`
with a `sleep of 1` second, but that does not work and i am not able to get the enter the value alone, every time the box adds "0." in the beginning of the code.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<td role="gridcell"><span style="width: 95px;" class="k-widget k-numerictextbox campaignBid"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default"><input type="text" class="k-formatted-value campaignBid k-input valid" tabindex="0" style="display: inline;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"><input type="text" style="display: none;" value="0.0079" class="campaignBid k-input valid" id="mb_2" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0.0079" aria-valuemax="1" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"><span class="k-select"><span class="k-link" unselectable="on"><span title="Increase value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" unselectable="on">Increase value</span></span><span class="k-link" unselectable="on"><span title="Decrease value" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">Decrease value</span></span></span></span></span></td>
```

Comment: There are two inputs which input you are targetting?

Comment: @Saifur I am targeting the first one

Comment: then please use `bvar = first(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]")` or simply `bvar = first(:xpath, "/td[7]//input[1]")`. It will target the first **input** tag

Comment: @Subh I tried using `bvar = first(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]") but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be simply doing

```
find(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]").set "" 
find(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]").set "Your value"
```

First line to clear the existing value

Comment: the first :xpath is resolved but the second one it says the element is not visible that is `first(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]").set "" ` works whereas `first(:xpath, "/td[7]/span/span/input[1]").set "Your value"` produces the error `"Element is not visible and so may not be interacted with(Selenium::Webdriver::Error::ElementNotVisisbleError)"`

Comment: Use some waits in that case possibly wait for on same element. Right after you clear the field

Comment: the result the same, same error Element not visible.

Comment: Can you please provide the html after clearing out the field? I want to see if any Ajax magic going on there

Comment: sure, i have cleared the field manually and pasted the html: in the question in the end. please refresh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67250/discussion-between-saifur-and-cage).